# connecting to Google Cloud Storage using gsutil from on premises server through border firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to connect from on premises linux server to Google Cloud Platform Storage (bucket) using gsutil. We have a border firewall which need to opened to connect to Cloud Storage. Firewall team is asking for destination details with port.

eg: through gs utility if I want to download the or upload the file I used the command gsutil cp test.txt gs://testbucket

Thanks,
Sahayam.J

Comment: I know it's been a while but whoever raised this query, did that answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood `gsutil` makes HTTPS requests to [Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/). So whitelisting `storage.googleapis.com` should suffice.